# Spreecommerce: custom style for a taxon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I wonder if there is a way to give a custom look and feel for particular taxon.

For example: I got a t-shirt, a coat, and a laptop pc. What I realy like to do is to create a page for "Great Outdoor Wear 2014" with a fancy look (and show the t-shirt and the coat there).

So I want to have:

1. a way to determine a css for particular taxon
2. a way to determine an html for that taxon

How do you deal with this kind of things?

Comment: @UriMikhli Actualy, I am talking about a new store and can use any version there. 
I love Spree. I wanted to know if it fitted my needs. And now I see that I can use my favorite framework :) Thank you!

Comment: no problem, It's a very flexible platform that's fun to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've done what you are asking in 1-3-stable using spree_static_content.**

- Create a link to your taxonomy, but have it routed to /pages/taxonomyname
- create a taxonomyname method in pages_controller to create the correct @products data and render the view you want.
- Create a pages static page called taxonomyname

**Lets walk through an example:**

- In routes.rb add aline

  get '/greatouterwear2014',to: 'page#greatouterwear2014',defaults: {:id => 'categories/greatouterwear2014'}
- In your menu create a link that looks like this `yourdomain/greatouterwear2014`
- In the pages controller:

  > ```
  >   def greatouterwear2014
  >      @taxon = .....etc
  >      @product = @taxon.product. ......etc
  >
  >     render 'greatouterwear2014'
  >   end
  > ```
- In `app/views/pages` create a file `greatouterwear2014.html.haml`(or your preferred templating suffix)
- In that file you can then organize and style the product list however you want.

I'm sure there are cleaner ways, but this works well enough for me in spree 1-3-stable